# fluentd -> logstash (net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder)

Tags: logstash, openshift, fluentd, elk

Does anyone have example fluentd & logstash config to make this scenario work?

My Java containers use Logback, with log output encoded into json by the logback LogstashEncoder.
Containers run in OpenShift which enforces use of "fluentd" for log forwarding.
We have fluentd pointing to a stand-alone ELK using its "fluentForward" capability.
On the logstash side we have nominated an input codec of fluent, and a json filter sourcing json from the message field.

We observe errors with text such as:  "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:1712"

I will happily share config here if that is helpful, but seeing some known-to-be-working example would also help.

**Kubernetes (OpenShift) ClusterLogForwarder**

```
apiVersion: logging.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterLogForwarder
spec:
  inputs:
    - application:
        namespaces:
          - unix
      name: my-app-logs
  outputs:
    - name: fluentd-server-insecure
      type: fluentdForward
      url: 'tcp://logstash.domain.com:24224'
  pipelines:
    - inputRefs:
        - application
        - audit
      name: forward-to-fluentd-insecure
      outputRefs:
        - fluentd-server-insecure
```

**Logstash Config**

```
input {
    tcp {
        host => "10.110.250.127"
        port => 24224
        codec => fluent
        type => "rsyslog"
    }
}
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        skip_on_invalid_json => true
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "rsyslog" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch.domain.com:9200" ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:1712
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you don't **have to** use the built-in logging functionality with OpenShift, but could instead deploy the [Elastic Cloud Operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html) and then use a `beat` if that suites your needs a little better.

However, if you want to stick to cluster-logging-operator, stick close to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-fluent.html):

```
    input {
      tcp {
        codec => fluent
        port => 4000
      }
    }
```

You are not receiving `rsyslog` type logs in this scenario, so don't specify that.

Additionally, if you're not doing any bigger processing in your logstash pipeline, which is what it looks like, I'd recommend for you to [forward directly](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/logging/cluster-logging-external.html#cluster-logging-collector-log-forward-es_cluster-logging-external) to the Elasticsearch instance:

```
apiVersion: "logging.openshift.io/v1"
kind: ClusterLogForwarder
metadata:
  name: instance 
  namespace: openshift-logging 
spec:
  outputs:
   - name: elasticsearch-insecure 
     type: "elasticsearch" 
     url: http://elasticsearch.insecure.com:9200
```

One last remark: make sure to always check if the versions you use are compatible. There is a lot of change ongoing with OpenShift clusterlogging and the forwarder so things might change. Red Hat provides [a table](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/logging/cluster-logging-external.html#cluster-logging-collector-log-forwarding-supported-plugins-5-2_cluster-logging-external) where you can look up the compatiblity

Comment: Thanks Rick.  Isn't the extraction of field values from the json contained in "message", i.e. the use of the json filter, the reason for using Logstash in this example?  Can elastic decode the json itself?

Comment: It should be able to do that itself. It just sticks each schema in it's own index, but there's some help how to work around that here https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/logging/cluster-logging-enabling-json-logging.html#cluster-logging-forwarding-json-logs-to-the-default-elasticsearch_cluster-logging-enabling-json-logging